# Meaning of NgRx createAction method's return type signature

Tags: typescript, generics, ngrx

I have been going through NgRx Doumentation for createAction method as in below link :
[Overloads for createAction method](https://ngrx.io/api/store/createAction#overloads)

I am not able to understand below in type signature of this method, specifically the return Type of createAction method :
   What is

```
() => TypedAction<T>
```

in this signature :

```
 ActionCreator<T, () => TypedAction<T>>
```

I don't see any reference to `TypedAction`? Does it mean any object of shape of specific Action type?

What I understand by T in above signature of return type is that it is generic type for ActionCreator function which will return Action of type T when called.
But Not sure the other Type argument indicates except that it seems to be some function which is returning `TypedAction` of type T. 
Would like to know a real world example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TypedAction` is a generic interface which extends Action type by adding a readonly `type` property.

```
export declare interface TypedAction<T extends string> extends Action {
  readonly type: T;
}
```

`ActionCreator<T, () => TypedAction<T>>` - tell us that we have a factory which returns a TypedAction object `() => ({ type: T})`

Let's define an action creator:

```
export const logout = createAction('[Auth] Logout');
```

`createAction` function is defined in action_creator.ts.

```
export function createAction<T extends string>(
  type: T
): ActionCreator<T, () => TypedAction<T>>;
```

from the declaration we can tell that `createAction` will return a function which in turn returns an object with a `type` property of string in our case as `<T extends string>`

Let's dive into the actual implementation a bit.
When you don't provide a payload for your action creator [the following code is executed](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/ccd3dd79ca7428999375153241fb0354216f9377/modules/store/src/action_creator.ts#L112):

```
export function createAction<T extends string, C extends Creator>(
  type: T,
  config?: { _as: 'props' } | C
): Creator {
...
    case 'empty':
      return defineType(type, () => ({ type }));
...
}
```

And defineType is:

```
function defineType(type: string, creator: Creator): Creator {
  return Object.defineProperty(creator, 'type', {
    value: type,
    writable: false,
  });
}
```

`defineType` accepts a type ('[Auth] Logout') and a Creator - `() => ({ type })`. It returns back Creator but with a new property `type`. 
So calling `logout.type` and `logout().type` will return the same value - '[Auth] Logout'

Later on, in the reducer_creator.ts it allows us to [extract ActionCreator type](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/ccd3dd79ca7428999375153241fb0354216f9377/modules/store/src/reducer_creator.ts#L186) ("[Auth] Logout" in our case), associate it to the reducer function and [execute it](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/ccd3dd79ca7428999375153241fb0354216f9377/modules/store/src/reducer_creator.ts#L237)

UPDATE:
As the answer to question became to big, I've decided to write a blog post [How do NgRx Action Creators work](https://link.medium.com/YFNfjwJIK1)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Another side query will be - using factory function notation in place where we use generic type is Typescript syntax? I did not find any specific example in docs where they have used factory function as generic type. using T is intuitive as it indicates the type argument the ActionCreator function will accept. However using another argument is confusing

Comment: Two types are needed, as the first one T is an input parameter and the second one is the output `() => TypedAction<T>`. Take a look on createAction declaration again `export function createAction<T extends string, C extends Creator>` it has an input parameter `type: T` and output is `Creator`.

Comment: isn't ActionCreator<T> correct output parameter of createAction? Why add extra parameter ?  () => TypedAction<T> is output parameter of ActionCreator function?

Comment: so as I understand createAction is function which accepts T as input param and returns ActionCreator<T> of type T. However why () => TypedAction<T> is added to ActionCreator?

Comment: it is slightly incorrect. createAction is itself of type ActionCreator (not it its return value). createAction accepts input string and outputs () => TypedAction<string> to be precise.